# erlang, ejabberd, how to deal with [{text, <<>>, <<"hello">>}] formats

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

So I got a hook in my code that says if an offline message is received, it will start up this function.

```
offline_msg_received(From, To, Packet) ->
```

The Packet has code looking like this:

```
{message,<<"purple2d957668">>,chat,<<>>,undefined,{jid,<<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"5280">>,<<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"5280">>},[],[{text,<<>>,<<"Hello">>}],undefined,[{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]}],#{}}
```

What I wanted out of this is the part containing my message. Which is:

```
[{text,<<>>,<<"Hello">>}]
```

I could get this part out with a pattern matching against the whole package variable. However, when I tried a pattern matching with my message, it says bad argument. I know that if I specify a variable with just

```
{text,<<>>,<<"Hello">>}
```

then I can pattern match against that. From my understanding, seeing [ ] around something means it is a list, or a string.

I can show some of the code here.

```
{P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10, P11} = Packet, %% P8 is the message I want.
?INFO_MSG("----------------------P8:  ~p~n", P8), %% This shows   {text,<<>>,<<"Hello">>}
{A, B, C} = P8,  %% This gives me a badmatch error.
```

Now, if I were to instead do this manually in the code shell:

```
{text,<<>>,<<"Hello">>} = P8,
{A, B, C} = P8,
```

Then the code works, and puts <<"Hello">> in the C variable.

My guess is that the [ ] around it in the "Package" variable has something to do with my badmatch error, but for some reason those symbols don't appear when I print out P8. Does anyone have a good suggestion why it doesn't work? I am guessing it has something to do with the hidden [ ], since otherwise it looks identical to my shell code test.

Thanks. This is my first time asking questions here, so I hope I didn't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the square brackets around the value in your `INFO_MSG` call is that `INFO_MSG` expects a *list* of values, not just a single value.  In the code above it happens to work out, since the format string only contains a single directive, and the value is a list of one element, so that's why the brackets are silently stripped out.

The `INFO_MSG` macro works the same as `io:format`, so you could try this out in the shell:

```
%% two arguments
io:format("~p ~p\n", [foo, bar]).
%% one argument - we still need square brackets
io:format("~p\n", [foo]).
```

---

You're doing this the hard way :) `message` and `text` are records defined in [xmpp_codec.hrl](https://github.com/processone/xmpp/blob/e005ff23da739926000966179067432a7709382c/include/xmpp_codec.hrl).  If you don't have the record definitions loaded in the shell, records look like a tuple with lots of elements, but if you load the record definitions, your message looks like this instead:

```
1> rr("include/xmpp_codec.hrl").
[address,addresses,adhoc_actions,adhoc_command,adhoc_note,
 bind,block,block_list,bob_data,bookmark_conference,
 bookmark_storage,bookmark_url,bytestreams,caps,
 carbons_disable,carbons_enable,carbons_private,
 carbons_received,carbons_sent,chatstate,client_id,compress,
 compress_failure,compressed,compression,csi,db_feature,
 db_result,db_verify|...]
2> {message,<<"purple2d957668">>,chat,<<>>,undefined,{jid,<<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"5280">>,<<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"5280">>},[],[{text,<<>>,<<"Hello">>}],undefined,[{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]}],#{}}. 
#message{id = <<"purple2d957668">>,type = chat,lang = <<>>,
         from = undefined,
         to = {jid,<<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"5280">>,
                   <<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"5280">>},
         subject = [],
         body = [#text{lang = <<>>,data = <<"Hello">>}],
         thread = undefined,
         sub_els = [{xmlel,<<"active">>,
                           [{<<"xmlns">>,
                             <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],
                           []}],
         meta = #{}}
```

The data you are looking for is in the `body` field.

Let's assign this record to the variable `M` and extract the body field:

```
4> Body = M#message.body.
[#text{lang = <<>>,data = <<"Hello">>}]
```

So that's a list containing one `text` record.  Let's extract the `data` field from that:

```
6> [#text{data = Data}] = Body.
[#text{lang = <<>>,data = <<"Hello">>}]
7> Data.
<<"Hello">>
```

---

That's how it works in the shell - load the record definitions with the `rr` function.  When writing a module that uses record definitions, you'd need to include the `hrl` file:

```
-include_lib("xmpp/include/xmpp_codec.hrl").
```

The `-include_lib` directory will look for the `xmpp` application on the load path, and search for the file `xmpp_codec.hrl` inside its `include` directory.  You may need to specify the code path to the compiler, something like `erlc -pa path/to/xmpp/ebin my_module.erl` - note that the `ebin` directory inside the application should be on the code path.

Comment: I would like to add, that in order to get text from `#message.body` it's better to use `xmpp:get_text/1` or `xmpp:get_text/2` function. The latter is usefull when you need to pick the text by language.
Another point is that you should not directly include `xmpp_codec.hrl`. Include `xmpp.hrl` instead.